# Problem with StringBuilder and JSON

Tags: c#, .net, sql, json, stringbuilder

I am trying to execute this code in C#.NET to turn an SQL table into a string with proper JSON;

```
json.AppendFormat("Places: [{{\"AvgDate\": \"{0}\"},\"MarkerID\": \"{1}\"}]", reader["AvgDate"], reader["MarkerID"]);
```

However it won't let me use the comma separation between the {0} and {1} indexes. The following works fine;

```
json.AppendFormat("Places: [{{\"AvgDate\": \"{0}\"}]", reader["AvgDate"], reader["MarkerID"]);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Closing braces must also be doubled in a format string:

```
json.AppendFormat("Places: [{{\"AvgDate\": \"{0}\"}},\"MarkerID\": \"{1}\"}]", reader["AvgDate"], reader["MarkerID"]);
```

Notice the `}}` after AvgDate:

Answer (score 2):

You've got a missing } in there...not sure if that's your exact problem, but its *a* problem....